# How do I change the xticks on a set boxplot subplots such that it is in words and complete?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I change the xticks on a set boxplot subplots such that name appears i.e. 'March' instead of 3.0 and the full year is included even if there are months without data?

I would like to have months in words as the xticks for a whole year, however my data varies in how complete it is i.e. some years have 7/12 months etc.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['month'] = df.index.month

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(15,15)) # create figure and axes

data = df.loc[:, ['scat450', 'scat550', 'scat700','bscat450','bscat550','bscat700', 'p_int', 'T_int', 'RH_int','month']]

varlist = ['scat450', 'scat550', 'scat700','bscat450','bscat550','bscat700', 'p_int', 'T_int', 'RH_int','month']
y_labels = ['Mm-1','Mm-1','Mm-1','Mm-1','Mm-1','Mm-1','mbar','celsius','%']

#Months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

df_12hourly = df[varlist].resample('12H').median()

for i,el in enumerate(list(df_12hourly.columns.values)[:-1]):
    a = df_12hourly.boxplot(el, by="month", showfliers=False, ax=axes.flatten()[i])   
    #a.set_xticklabels(df.month, rotation=45 )
    #a.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b"))
    a.set_ylabel(y_labels[i])
    a.set_xlim(0,13)
    fig.suptitle(str(year), fontsize=16)
```

Comment: Rather than integers 1..12 for the `df['month']` column, use datetime.datetime values: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Comment: I added Import calendar df['month'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x]) However, I just get the error message KeyError: 'month'